# How to run Koa server before Tests in Mocha?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, koa

I read a lot of answers to similar questions already but can't figure out what is wrong in my code.

this is my server.js file

```
const Koa = require('koa')
const Router = require('koa-router')

const app = new Koa()

app.use(require('koa-bodyparser')())

const login = (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.body = ctx.request.body
}

const router = new Router({ prefix: '/api' })

router.get('/test', (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.body = { resp: 'GET REQUEST /test WORKING' }
})
router.post('/login', login)

app.use(router.routes())

module.exports = app
```

this is my index.js file

```
const server = require('./server')

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('App is running on http://localhost:3000')
})
```

and this is my mocha test file

```
const axios = require('axios').default
const expect = require('chai').expect
const app = require('./server')

describe('7-module-3-task', () => {
  describe('test', function () {
    let server

    before(done => {
      server = app.listen(3000, done)
    })

    after(async () => {
      server.close()
    })

    it('should return response from server', async () => {

      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/test')

      expect(response.data, 'should return object with key "resp').to.have.property('resp')
    })
  })
})
```

It's working okay when I make a request in Postman. I tried multiple options already but I still get 404 response, as I understand test is performed before server started running...? How can I make it working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shared the same code with 2 of my friends and they managed to run tests successfully.

I tested it on my other laptop after this and tests worked as well.

The problem was in the port. 3000 port was used as a default one in the debugger in Webstorm, not sure why but still.

Launching the server on port 3000 in a regular way, not in mocha tests, worked very well but in tests, it did not work, not sure why.

So for those who ever face something similar, check the default port of the debugger or any other built-in server.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would move the startup (`app.listen`) directly into the server.js (not critical, but maybe more simpler because the `require` in your test would then already start your server:

```
const Koa = require('koa')
const Router = require('koa-router')

const app = new Koa()

app.use(require('koa-bodyparser')())

const router = new Router({ prefix: '/api' })

router.get('/test', (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.body = { resp: 'GET REQUEST /test WORKING' }
})

app.use(router.routes())

app.listen(3000); // can be a parameter but for simplicity hardcoded here

module.exports = app
```

In your test you then do:

```
let chai = require('chai');
let chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
let server = require('./server'); // this will already start up your server

describe('API Tests', () => {
    describe('TEST endpoint', () => {
        it('It should GET response from test endpoint', (done) => {
            chai.request('http://localhost:3000')
                .get('/api/test/')          // be sure to have a trailing '/' !!
                .end((err, res) => {
                    res.body.should.have.property('resp');
                    done();
                });
        })
    });
 });
```

**One more hint:** maybe in your original code you just have to make sure, that you have a trailing `/` when calling your route in the test.

Code snippets not testet but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it doesn't work either. The weirdest thing is I shared the code I initially posted here with 2 of my friends and tests work fine for them. I started thinking it might be some local problem with my laptop. However, I have no idea what can be wrong and what I should check...Google doesn't really help :)